# What does "./" mean in linux shell?

Tags: command-line, scripts

What does the command `./` mean? For example, sometimes we call a file with `./config`, sometimes `../config`, thanks

Comment: There almost certainly is a duplicate out there @Joren but in this case, that isn't a good one as it doesn't really explain anything about why it's required for executing things. Edit: Hmm maybe I'm making a bad assumption about it being executable.

Comment: `./some_file` means run some_file in the current directory. `../some_file` means run some file in the parent directory.  Perhaps this question explains it better: [Why do I need to type `./` before executing a program in the current directory?](http://askubuntu.com/q/320632/107450)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`./config` means you're calling something in the current working directory. In this case config is an executable. You have to specify the path for executables if they're outside your $PATH variable and that's why `config` isn't enough.

`../config` would be used if the `config` executable were in the parent of the current working directory.