# Zip2john issue on ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: command-line, software-installation, compiling, directory, paths

Problem:
    root@ITSASECRET:~/src/john/run#  zip2john
    : command not found

I want to add that the srcript is in the directory. I also had a lot of trouble installing Rexgen as well as Bison and flex AND CMAKE. I had to use several different guides to get it done.

MY build:

```
Target CPU ................................. x86_64 AVX2, 64-bit LE
AES-NI support ............................. run-time detection
Target OS .................................. linux-gnu
Cross compiling ............................ no
Legacy arch header ......................... x86-64.h

Optional libraries/features found:
Memory map (share/page large files) ........ yes
Fork support ............................... yes
OpenMP support ............................. yes (not for fast formats)
OpenCL support ............................. yes
Generic crypt(3) format .................... yes
libgmp (PRINCE mode and faster SRP formats)  yes
128-bit integer (faster PRINCE mode) ....... yes
libz (pkzip format, gpg2john) .............. yes
libbz2 (gpg2john extra decompression logic)  yes
libpcap (vncpcap2john and SIPdump) ......... yes
librexgen (regex cracking mode) ............ yes
OpenMPI support (default disabled) ......... yes
ZTEX USB-FPGA module 1.15y support ......... no

Install missing libraries to get any needed features that were omitted.

Configure finished.
```

So after I did this:

Make process completed.

```
root@ITSASECRET:~/src/john/src# zip2john
zip2john: command not found
```

Then I tried this thinking I needed to be in the directory:

```
root@ITSASECRET:~/src/john/run# zip2john
zip2john: command not found
```

I have been trying to get this working for months. What am I doing wrong or not doing?

If anyone can tell me how to add this to path so I can run the commands without going to this directory that would also be nice.

Comment: See [Why do I need to type `./` before executing a program in the current directory?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/320632/why-do-i-need-to-type-before-executing-a-program-in-the-current-directory)

Comment: ... and [How to add a directory to the PATH?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/60218/how-to-add-a-directory-to-the-path)

Comment: Thank you Steeldriver. I think I was running low on sleep ./ is what I needed toi execute... Now if I can make sense of the path guide you linked to we will be golden!

Answer (score 1):

'I want to clarify for anyone having the same issue. Other systems such as Kalilinux have been streemlined through path. Answers were provided by a comment from the user Steeldriver.
To use a program in a directory not in path Such as john jumbo you must type the following.

`cd`
and on the same line you must type the address of the directory it should look like this:

```
cd /directory/subfolder/runfolder
```

As per my install of John it is this command yours may be in another folder:

```
cd /src/john/run
```

This will put you in the correct place.
Then to run you must type`./` before before the program script

```
./zip2john
```

On path I can not help you as I am still having some issues when I figure out the guide I will try to edit in the information so that you do not have to type so much when using John Jumbo. Again thank you to the community for helping me.

Note on cd... To move 1 up it is `cd ..`
I request this is kept as most guides would lead the end user into thinking john jumbo does not need to be executed like this when in fact it does on ubuntu.

EDIT: Be careful of spacing and capitalization when adding files to $PATH.\
The simplest guide is here: [How to add an entire directory to path](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-add-directories-to-your-path-in-linux/)