# chmod does nothing when i try to install a sh file

Tags: command-line, bash, permissions, scripts

I'm trying to install the poweriso sh file (along with other sh files) onto my system, but it doesn't seem to work ( the outcome is the same on all sh files). I did some research on how to install sh files, various forums and youtube videos seem to conclude that I am in fact doing it right. but why isn't it installing? when I run

```
sudo chmod +x poweriso.sh
```

or

```
sudo chmod +x ./poweriso.sh
```

they gave me the same output, which is nothing, literally nothing, like I didn't even type anything. no error, nothing. what am I doing wrong?

Comment: The command chmod does not run a script, only changes if it's executable or not. After marking it as executable, you have to *execute* it: `./poweriso.sh`

Comment: Hi, I just typed sudo chmod +x poweriso.sh then sudo poweriso.sh but it returned with bash: poweriso.sh: command not found Am I missing something? :(

Comment: `sudo ./poweriso.sh` - see [Why do I need to type `./` before executing a program in the current directory?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/320632/why-do-i-need-to-type-before-executing-a-program-in-the-current-directory)

Comment: same outcome 
sudo: ./poweriso.sh: command not found

Comment: @LukeWatson in that case, a file of the name `poweriso.sh` does not exist in the current directory

Comment: Or the shebang line points to a nonexistent interpreter. `head -n 1 ./poweriso.sh`. Look at the file `less poweriso.sh`. Watch it at work: `sudo bash -x ./poweriso.sh`

Comment: Probably the file is a binary. Try to run `poweriso -?`

Answer (score 1):

The command `chmod` does not run a script. **It only marks it as executable or not**.

You can verify if a file is executable running the command `ls -l your_file`, which will output something like this:

```
-rw-r--r--  1 user  user          0 jul  5 16:34 your_file
```

As you see there is no `x` in the first column, meaning that the file is not executable.

Let's the mark it as executable:

```
$ chmod +x your_file
```

Check again with `ls -l your_file`:

```
-rwxr-xr-x  1 user  user          0 jul  5 16:34 your_file
```

Now the `x` means that it is executable and you can run it typing

```
$ ./your_file
```

---

Note: There's of course the matter of permissions, users and groups, but that's another monster that may make the answer much more complicated than needed.

Comment: Hi, I tried running `chmod +x poweriso` then `ls -l poweriso` but instead of giving me `x`, it gives me `-rw-r--r-- 1 luke luke 1929800 Mar 19 04:55 poweriso`
attempting to run it results in `bash: ./poweriso: Permission denied`

Comment: @LukeWatson please edit your question to include the output of `findmnt -T ./`