# bash doesn't recognize script

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I'm quiet new to scripting and trying to learn from videos and books.
When I write my first script the bash took it as a command not an executable (yes I used 775). Here's an example for script and the bash error:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo"TTTTTTT"
exit
turan_first: command not found
```

I'm so new that I even don't know the problem is. Please help.

Comment: You need a space between `echo` and `"TTTTTTT"`.

Comment: Did you type `./turan_first` to run it - or just `turan_first`? See [Why do I need to type `./` before executing a program in the current directory?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/320632/why-do-i-need-to-type-before-executing-a-program-in-the-current-directory)

Comment: I just wrote turan_first. Because the guys on videos did the same. And I was in the same directory at the time I typed the command.

Answer (score 2):

When you invoke a program or a script, the shell looks for it the directories declared in the `PATH` variable. Except if you invoke the program file specifying a path -absolute or relative-
Of course the user calling the script or program file must have executable permission right on the file

```
aprogram          ## Looks for the file in directories declared in PATH
/path/to/aprogram ## Looks for aprogram in /path/to
./aprogram        ## Looks in current directory for aprogram
```

See `echo $PATH`


`~/turan_first` executable file contains

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "TTTTTTT"
exit
```

- A space is required after the command `echo`, or shell wont recognize it
- `exit` is useless while the script ends normally
- Call the script with `~/turan_first` or while prompt is in `~/`, call it with `./turan_first`

---

A good practice is to store all your script in a dedicated directory. Say `~/Scripts`
In that case, you get the habit to call your scripts with `~/Scripts/turan_first` using auto-completion.
A next step could be to add your Scripts directory to the PATH environment variable. So that you could call your scripts without any path specified.
Edit the bashrc file: `nano ~/.bashrc` and add the line

```
export PATH="~/Scripts:$PATH"
```

Comment: Also need `chmod a+x ~/turan_first` to make script executable.

Comment: Thanks for all your help. It's more than I expected. I will do the things that you suggest. But something isn't still clear. I watched 2 videos from different tubers and they didn't need to add ./ or ~/ before the command. They just typed and there was the echo. Is it about some adjustments in .bashrc or it's something that I don't understand?

Comment: videos are not reference, you should better read