# CP2K executable will not execute in its directory, why and what is the solution?

Tags: command-line, permissions

I have an executable called cp2k.sopt located in ~/cp2k/exe/local. When I change to this directory and type cp2k.sopt --version, I get the message shown in the attached image, which also shows that the file is executable (from the output of the ls -la command).

[image: Screenshot showing where and how the problem arises]

I am running 18.04.4 LTS, and your help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please see [Why do I need to type `./` before executing a program in the current directory?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/320632/why-do-i-need-to-type-before-executing-a-program-in-the-current-directory)

Comment: [Please don't post images of text](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/8713/85695). Instead, paste the text directly into your question ([edit]) and use the [formatting tools](https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting).

Comment: Problem solved. Thank you very much steeldriver.