# Open pl command

Tags: command-line, perl

This is probably pretty basic but I have not been able to solve it.  I am trying to execute IDrive for Linux, and following the instructions I need to run `account_setting.pl.`  I open the terminal where the file as by opening the terminal in the folder I do not have to put in the path to the file. In the terminal I type `sudo account_setting.pl`
However, after entering my password I get the response that the command is not found.  See below.

```
alan@alan-HPProDesk-600-G1-TWR:~/IDriveForLinux/scripts$ sudo account_setting.pl
[sudo] password for alan: 
sudo: account_setting.pl: command not found
```

I have tried without the pl, have made sure that perl is installed, ensured I have permissions etc. - all to no avail.  There must be something I am missing, but what?

Comment: Possibly what you are missing is `./` - see [Why do I need to type `./` before executing a program in the current directory?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/320632/why-do-i-need-to-type-before-executing-a-program-in-the-current-directory)

Comment: Thank you - it worked!  I had tried using the path but must have had a mistake there also.  It is much easier opening the terminal in the folder.

Comment: @Skypilot: Always use [tab] completion, then this can't happen. And you save quite some typing as well.