# configure seems missing for glibc

Tags: glibc

I have follow the INSTALL documentation for run your command line advice but the glibc program unwant to do your advice,

the command line is the following :

```
root@ubuntu-ThinkPad-X250:/home/ubuntu/programs/glibc-2.31/src/gnu/glibc-build# configure --prefix=usr CC="gcc -m32" CFLAGS="-O3"
  configure : commande introuvable
```

Thank you in advance to help myself fully install your program,

Regards.

Dorian ROSSE.

Comment: Welcome to Askubuntu!

Please can you include the OS and details of it ?  (such as; version, LTS? , what kind of Ubuntu? and version of the program(link to it?) ) and if applicable - any log file *maybe from make, or similar

Wishes!

Comment: Why are you running as root? Why are you trying to build libc6 from source? Both those things are red flags for breaking things fast. Regardless, unless the current working directory is on root's `PATH`, you need `./configure` not just `configure` - see [Why do I need to type `./` before executing a program in the current directory?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/320632/why-do-i-need-to-type-before-executing-a-program-in-the-current-directory)

Comment: Why not: `sudo apt update && sudo apt install glibc` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: sudo apt install glibc
E: Impossible de trouver le paquet glibc

Comment: /glibc-2.31# ./configure && make && make install

Comment: configure: error: you must configure in a separate build directory

Comment: /glibc-2.31/build# ./configure && make && make install
-bash: ./configure: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type

Comment: /glibc-2.31/build# configure && make && make install
configure : commande introuvable

Comment: /glibc-2.31/src/gnu/glibc-build# ./configure && make && make install
-bash: ./configure: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type

Comment: /glibc-2.31/src/gnu/glibc-build# configure && make && make install
configure : commande introuvable

Comment: like you see all command line fail and apt install glibc doesn't find a package glibc

Comment: I went to follow the reame INSTALL finaly :

Comment: /glibc-2.31/src/gnu/glibc-build# ./configure CC="gcc -m32" CFLAGS="-O3"
-bash: ./configure: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
root@ubuntu-ThinkPad-X250:/home/ubuntu/programs/glibc-2.31/src/gnu/glibc-build# configure && make && make install
configure : commande introuvable

Comment: /glibc-2.31/src/gnu/glibc-build# configure CC="gcc -m32" CFLAGS="-O3"
configure : commande introuvable